# add a class when div over another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery code that adds a class to a div(#menu) after the user scrolled that far on a page. But I am searching for a way to change that code into adding that class when the div(#menu) is on top of another div with the class(.remove) and remove the class again when it's on a div with the class(.add). Here is my code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 400; // distance to trigger
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
        jQuery('#menu').addClass('scrolled');
    }else{
        jQuery('#menu').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say "`on top of`", do you mean like above the div or literally on top of it? Also: "`on a div`" means the same thing?

Comment: the menu is fixed and it is a long page with multiple div's with the size of the viewport with means that if you scroll down the menu scrolls over the div's

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example of the markup that would trigger each scenario?

Comment: How to detect if a fixed div is on top of another div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the position of the div that you want to "be on top of".

To do that you can use

`$('.remove').offset().top;`

Hope this helps.